# ExtJS, how to nest the red and green container (Layer 2) inside of Layer 1 body? I want the red and green containers inside Layer 1

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2DH3.png)
How I want it to look ^

Current Code:

Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
width: '100%',
layout: 'vbox',
renderTo: document.body,
defaults: {
xtype: 'container',
width: '50%',
layout: 'vbox',
border: 0
},
items: [{
bodyStyle: {},
defaults: {
style: {},
},
items: [{}]
}, {
items: [{
xtype: 'container',
style: {},
}, {
xtype: 'container',
style: {
'background': 'grey',
'color': 'white',
'font-size': '15px',
},
width: '100%',
height: 50,
html: 'Layer 1 Header'
}, {
xtype: 'container',
style: {
'background': 'lightgrey',
'color': 'black',
'font-size': '15px',
},
width: '100%',
height: 200,
html: 'Layer 1 Body'
}, ]
}, {
xtype: 'container',
style: {
'background': 'darkred',
'color': 'white',
'font-size': '15px',
},
width: '25%',
height: 200,
html: 'Layer 2 Left'
}, {
xtype: 'container',
style: {
'background' : 'darkgreen',
'color' : 'white',
'font-size': '15px',
'pack': 'center',
},
width: '25%',
height: 200,
html: 'Layer 2 Right'
}
]
});

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `vbox` / `hbox` layout with `align` set to `stretch` in order to achieve this layout. Check this code, tested in a Fiddle (ExtJS 7.3.0 - Material, classic toolkit):

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            renderTo: document.body,
            items: [{
                    xtype: 'container',
                    style: {
                        'background': 'grey',
                        'color': 'white',
                        'font-size': '15px',
                    },
                    height: 50,
                    html: 'Layer 1 Header'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'hbox',
                        align: 'stretch'
                    },
                    items: [, {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        flex: 1,
                        height: 200,
                        style: {
                            'background': 'darkred',
                            'color': 'white',
                            'font-size': '15px',
                        },
                        html: 'Layer 2 Left'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        flex: 1,
                        height: 200,
                        style: {
                            'background': 'darkgreen',
                            'color': 'white',
                            'font-size': '15px'
                        },
                        html: 'Layer 2 Right'
                    }]
                }

            ]

        });
    }
});
```